# sum graph from bottom to top

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

given the following graph modeled in neo4j

[image]

goal:

calculate the sum of all nodes multiplied by the edge percentage from the bottom up.

e.g.

```
(((30*.6)+(50*.1)+100)*.5)+10)=71,5
```

status:

I found the `REDUCE` function (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-collection.html#functions-reduce)
but in my opinion it sums from top to the bottom, instead of bootom up.

Is this a commen problem with a well known name, and I dont know it?
Is there any solution in neo4j or in another (graph)database/language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a really interesting one :

I assumed 2 things, first all nodes have the `:A` label, second the property on nodes and relationship has the key `p`

Here is a working query :

```
MATCH p=(:A)-[r]->(pike)
WITH pike, collect(p) as paths
OPTIONAL MATCH (pike)-[r]->()
WITH 
CASE r WHEN null THEN 1 ELSE r.p END as multiplier, 
CASE r WHEN null THEN last(nodes(paths[0])).p 
ELSE reduce(x=0, path in paths | x + (head(nodes(path)).p * head(rels(path)).p)) + last(nodes(paths[0])).p END as total
RETURN sum(total*multiplier) as total
```

The logic behind :

1. Find one depths paths, agreggate the children by the pike (first `WITH`)
2. In case the optional match doesn't pass, the multiplier will be 1 instead of a possible float value on the relationship property
3. The second case, do the math logic, if this is the top of the pikes (hence here node `A`) it will just add the value of the top node, otherwise it will take the value of the children
4. Then it sum the score + the multiplication

You can test it here : http://console.neo4j.org/r/ih8obf